# TextEdit Бегущая строка

Tags: android

Необходимо организовать бегущую строку, для TextView.
Если все делаю для одного TextView  на пустой  activity, то все работает.
У меня этот фрагмент кода находится в LinearLayout, который в свою очередь находится в NavigationView  и эффекта бегущей строки нету,сколько есть помещается остальное обрезается.

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewPlayerTrackInfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/nv_player_track_info_margin"
                    android:text="4/17 Интересные факты о траля-ля траляля бегущая строка"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/nv_player_track_info_text_size" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все оказалось просто, чтобы строка бежала элемент должен быть выбран, чему NavigationView  мешает.
Выбираю принудительно в коде.

```
 textViewPlayerTrackInfo.setSelected(true);
```